# Inserting sleep inside a particular function in Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, get, sleep, custom-function

I'm trying to pull data out of an API from a third party and inserting into Google Sheets. However this third party only allows 3 requests per minute, so I'm trying to use a Utilities.sleep feature inside the function I'm building for this request.

My sheet looks like this:

[image]

It has the two inputs necessary for the function I'm using (this below):

```
function GET_DETAILS_RECEITA(CNPJ,sleep_seconds) {
  Utilities.sleep(sleep_seconds*1000);

  var fields = 'nome,fantasia,email,telefone';
  var baseUrl = 'https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/';
  var queryUrl = baseUrl + CNPJ;

  if (CNPJ == '') {
    return 'Give me CNPJ...';
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var place = JSON.parse(json);

  return [[ place.nome,
            place.fantasia,
            place.telefone,
            place.email,
          ]];
}
```

Technically it should work but for some reason I'm getting a return only in the first one.

[image]

The error I'm getting is very generic "Erro: Erro interno ao executar a função personalizada." (something like "Error: Internal error in the execution of personalized function").

Any ideas?

Comment: You're definitely going to want explicit control over the use of an API that limits you to 3 / min. Custom functions do not provide you with the necessary tooling you will want.

Answer (score 1):

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

> A custom function call must return within 30 seconds. If it does not, the cell will display an error: Internal error executing the custom function.

Considering the above, it's not a good idea to use `sleep` on a custom function that will be used as intended by the OP. Instead use a custom menu or the Script Editor to execute a script.

In order to minimize changes to your function, you could use a function that read/write the values to the spreadsheet and pass the required arguments to `GET_DETAILS_RECEITA`

Comment: actually I'm using that in the script editor. should that timeout as well?

Comment: @abutremutante Please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using something like this in a dialog.  You can pass an extra parameter in the set interval as long as your using Chrome.

```
<script>
var CNPJ='what ever';
window.onload=function(){setInterval(getDetails,25000,CNPJ);}
function getDetails(CNPJ){
  google.script.run.GET_DETAILS_RECEITA(CNPJ)
}
</script>
```

And if you want a callback then use with withSuccessHandler();